# NuGetSdkResolver.dll is mssiing

Tags: c#

May I know how can I install the above file in my PC? I just cannot find it.

*\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\Microsoft.Build.NuGetSdkResolver.dll
*

Answer (score 1):

FYI,

Just go to download the nuget.exe, run cmd as administrator, then cd to the above path, then run " nuget.exe install Microsoft.Build.NuGetSdkResolver -Version 5.0.0-preview1.5673 -Source https://dotnet.myget.org/F/nuget-build/api/v3/index.json" commnad (copy and paste). DLL will installed it in one of the folder.

Comment: This command: `nuget.exe install Microsoft.Build.NuGetSdkResolver -Source https://dotnet.myget.org/F/nuget-build/api/v3/index.json -Source nuget.org` resulted in the .dll file -- but still didn't run.

Answer (score 0):

I just started VS Installer and reinstalled nuget dependency. This file appeared.